# alert script and response.redirect on aspx and .cs page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have used this scriptmanager in my aspx page.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Redit", "alert('Registered Successfully !!'); window.location='" + Request.ApplicationPath + "/admin/CreateSubAdmin.aspx';", true);
```

when i am using it in local server than it is working correctly. and url look like : host url:xyz.aspx/admin/CreateSubAdmin.aspx

Underline section is in admin section.

but on server this is not properly working. its look like : /admin/CreateSubAdmin.aspx only.

but i want it to show like www.xyz.com/admin/CreateSubAdmin.aspx.

so what i was write wrong. plz help me.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The only that you must done is to remove the `ApplicationPath`, or remove the first slash.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Redit",
 "alert('Registered Successfully !!'); window.location='" + Request.ApplicationPath + "admin/CreateSubAdmin.aspx';", true);
```

or

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Redit", 
 "alert('Registered Successfully !!'); window.location='/admin/CreateSubAdmin.aspx';", true);
```

The issue here is how to make the full url that works on your case.

You can alternative think to build it using the `"http:" + Request.Url.Host` to have the full url

Answer (score 0):

I use a helper function like this:

```
public static string GetApplicationRoot()
{
    string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
    string applicationPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
    if (applicationPath == "/")
    {
        return host;
    }
    else
    {
        return host + applicationPath;
    }
}
```